# Why do logical operators negate their argument when there is only one argument in R?

Tags: r, boolean-expression

When passing only a single vector to the logical and/or operator, the operator negates the argument:

```
> x = c(F,T,T)
> `&`(x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> `|`(x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

To make the logical operator work as idempotent, one needs to pass a single element vector as the second argument:

```
> `&`(x,T)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> `|`(x,F)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Why do the logical operators negate their argument when there is only one argument passed?

Comment: You would think "invalid unary operator" would be a more appropriate response, that is what ` `*`(3)  ` does for example.

Comment: What `R` version are you using? Because I only get `Error in |x: 1 argument passed to '|' which requires 2` in your unary example.

Comment: "Works"  (as in I get this strange negation behavior) for me and I am using Version 0.98.1103

Comment: That's most likely your `Rstudio` version. Current `R` is on major version `3.x.x`.

Comment: I have `R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)` on osx `x86_64, darwin13.4.0`.

Comment: I'm on `R  version 3.1.2` which means PR#16385 is probably already applied. This patch fixes this behaviour.  I'ts odd that you still experience this behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [was modified in R 3.2.1](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/92a97e58379cedb5879f2eb136eae3b2fd3be7bb) as a result of [a bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16385). As you've pointed out, the previous behavior made little sense:

[image]

Comment: @Pascal This is <3.2.1 behavior. In current R version, you should be getting the error noted in comments above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951729/why-do-logical-operators-negate-their-argument-when-there-is-only-one-argument-i/30951871?noredirect=1#comment49937120_30951729